# Saving a pandas dataframe to separate jsons without NaNs

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe with some NaN values.

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,np.nan,1],[2,2,np.nan], [np.nan, 3, 3], [4,4,4],[np.nan,np.nan,5], [6,np.nan,np.nan]])
```

It looks like:

[image]

What I did after to get a json:

```
sample_df.to_json(orient = 'records')
```

Which gives:

```
'[{"0":1.0,"1":null,"2":1.0},{"0":2.0,"1":2.0,"2":null},{"0":null,"1":3.0,"2":3.0},{"0":4.0,"1":4.0,"2":4.0},{"0":null,"1":null,"2":5.0},{"0":6.0,"1":null,"2":null}]'
```

I want to save this dataframe to a json with 2 rows in each json, but with none of the Nan values. Here is how I tried to do it:

```
df_dict = dict((n, sample_df.iloc[n:n+2, :]) for n in range(0, len(sample_df), 2))

for k, v in df_dict.items():
    print(k)
    print(v)
    for d in (v.to_dict('record')):
        for k,v in list(d.items()):
            if type(v)==float:
                if math.isnan(v):
                    del d[k]

json.dumps(df_dict)
```

Output I want:

'[{"0":1.0,"2":1.0},{"0":2.0,"1":2.0}]' -> in one .json file
'[{"1":3.0,"2":3.0},{"0":4.0,"1":4.0,"2":4.0}]' -> in second .json file
'[{"2":5.0},{"0":6.0}]' -> in third .json file

Comment: Dataframe + expected output will help a lot! Thanks.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Added! Sorry for not giving enough detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply` to drop `NaN`s, `groupby` to group and `dfGroupBy.apply` to JSONify.

```
s = sample_df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().to_dict(), 1)\
        .groupby(sample_df.index // 2)\
        .apply(lambda x: x.to_json(orient='records'))
s    

0            [{"0":1.0,"2":1.0},{"0":2.0,"1":2.0}]
1    [{"1":3.0,"2":3.0},{"0":4.0,"1":4.0,"2":4.0}]
2                            [{"2":5.0},{"0":6.0}]
dtype: object
```

---

Finally, iterate over `.values` and save to separate JSON files.

```
import json
for i, j_data in enumerate(s.values):
    json.dump(j_data, open('File{}.json'.format(i + 1), 'w'))
```

Comment: What if I changed the original dataframe's index to be a column with strings in the data and I wanted the same output? I get the error  TypeError: cannot perform __floordiv__ with this index type: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>.

Comment: @pr338 Use `np.arange(df.shape[0]) // 2`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant the output with the index being a string like "indexhere"    [{"fund.numeric.returnY3CategoryRank":0,"fund.... Going to edit original question with another example if this is still not clear.

Comment: @pr338 Ah, sorry... things are getting jumbled up. Can you ask a new question?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
with open("data.json","w") as fpout:
    fpout.write("{\n")
    for row_id in range(sample_df.shape[0]):
        fpout.write("\t" + str(sample_df.index[row_id]) + ":" + sample_df.iloc[row_id].dropna().to_json(orient="index") + "\n")
    fpout.write("}\n")
```