# Converting a pandas DF to JSON without NAN

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a DF that looks something like:

```
A    B    C    D    E
1    1    NaN  1    1
NaN  2    3    4    NaN
```

When I do:

```
df.to_json(orient='records')
```

I get something like

```
[{"A":1,"B":1,"C":null,"D":1,"E":1},{"A":null,"B":2,"C":3,"D":4,"E":null}]
```

Is there anyway to get it to ignore anything that has NaN and show something like:

```
[{"A":1,"B":1,"D":1,"E":1},{"B":2,"C":3,"D":4}]
```

Can I do this using pandas?

Comment: This is close enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166112/saving-a-pandas-dataframe-to-separate-jsons-without-nans -- I don't know whether it'd be considered a duplicate or not on StackOverflow (I'm relatively new).

Comment: Let me offer the solution and close it `[dict(zip(x.index.get_level_values(1),x)) for _,x in df.replace('NAN',np.nan).stack().groupby(level=0)]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
[{**x[i]} for i, x in df.stack().groupby(level=0)]

[{'A': 1.0, 'B': 1.0, 'D': 1.0, 'E': 1.0}, {'B': 2.0, 'C': 3.0, 'D': 4.0}]
```

If you want `int`

```
[{**x[i]} for i, x in df.stack().map(int).groupby(level=0)]

[{'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'D': 1, 'E': 1}, {'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4}]
```

Hacky way to keep `int` if they are `int`

```
[{**x[i]} for i, x in df.stack().fillna(0, downcast='infer').groupby(level=0)]

[{'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'D': 1, 'E': 1}, {'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4}]
```

---

#### Explanation

```
#    Series with a
#       MultiIndex       Make a Series and drop nulls
#                ↓       ↓                     ↓ Essentially grouping by `index` of `df`
[{**x[i]} for i, x in df.stack().groupby(level=0)]
# ↑   ↑
# ↑   Slice the MultiIndex with name of the group
# Unpack in a dictionary context with double splat `{**mydict} == mydict`
```

Comment: Good!  I expect I'll see it in upcoming answers (-:

Answer (score 0):

Here is a previous answer for removing dicitonary keys when their values are null:

```
{k: v for k, v in metadata.items() if v is not None}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118700/8265971

For pandas, there is a `pandas.DataFrame.dropna` function. If those values will be assigned to a column, this would work nicely:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: @gmuraleekrishna why would you delete and replace my answers with my original answers? You didn't actually edit anything.